# Why can't jQuery find next() when surrounded by certain tags?

Tags: jquery

When I have elements surrounded by a P tag, or SPAN tag, why does jQuery fail to find next(), even though the element does indeed have a direct sibling?

```
<p>
 <img src="" width="40" height="40"
  onmouseover="alert('next() is ' + $(this).next().length)" />
  &lt;-- mouseover me
 <div></div>
</p>​
```

If I change the P tag to a SPAN tag, same problem occurs. If I remove the P tag or change it to almost any other tag, it works fine.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YHTGT/

Comment: Side note: I'm using jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: You should define "fail" for the benefit of the question.

Comment: Because `p` elements cannot contain `div` elements. Look at the generated DOM structure. The browser moves the `div` after the `p`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Bah, beat me by 21 seconds...

Comment: Why would you use inline event handlers if you're using jQuery? HTML belongs in `.html` files, CSS belongs in `.css` files, JS belongs in `.js` files.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I reckon it's acceptable for the purpose of keeping this testcase nice and minimal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, jQuery's *more* minimal than trying to build a string that evaluates to valid JavaScript code.

Comment: @zzzzBov: For your computer, yes. For your eyes reading a Stack Overflow question? No, not at all. Remember that for Javascript it's not a string at all; it's only a string for the HTML layer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, [I strongly disagree with your statement.](http://jsfiddle.net/Cvw4s/)

Comment: @zzzzBov: I don't understand what sort of point you're trying to make. Yes, you can post a testcase with distinct Javascript on jsfiddle.net; well done! That has nothing to do with a neat, encapsulated six-line testcase in plain text on a SO question that I can read in seconds.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I made the statement that JavaScript should be separated from HTML in the same way that CSS should be separated from HTML. If I were to post a CSS question, I would post both CSS and HTML parts, and not shove the styles inline. All I'm trying to do is teach people how to write code in a way that wont bite them in the ass a week later. It'll take someone new to JavaScript quite a while to figure out why `<img onclick="if (a == "b") doStuff()" />` is failing, when the whole issue is avoided by keeping them entirely separate.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Again, I'm sure it was written only this way to present the scenario, and not because the OP thinks it's a good idea in real life. i.e. a contrived example. I'd just let it go.

Comment: Lightness is correct zzzzBov. I simply formatted it this way to keep the question short and concise.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I've met too many so-called developers who have no idea how to use jQuery for binding events. I **never** assume that anyone who puts event management inline knows how to do it any other way. And, more importantly, beginners who are looking at these questions as examples would be presented with the wrong approach to solving problems.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Well, if we were forced to write every question on SO so that it is suitable without prejudice to the lowest common denominator, then we wouldn't get very far, would we? If someone is trying to learn from arbitrary Stack Overflow _questions_ then that's their responsibility; they should instead be learning from _answers_ and peer-reviewed books and anything else is going to yield Undefined Behaviour. This is a volunteer community and [the lie to children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) self-applies.

Comment: I love Stackoverflow, but it does seem to bring out the nit-picky perfectionist in all of us. You too, Lightness: You asked me to define "fail". What part of "jQuery fails to find next" needs clarifying? jQuery fails to find the next element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`div` is not a valid node within a `p` node, so the parser is probably eliding it entirely. If it had content, I'd expect it to be moved in the DOM tree to *after* the `p` node, making it *not* a sibling of the `img`.

Changing the `div` to a `span` [works](http://jsfiddle.net/HMCan/) because the `span` is allowed there.

Comment: Interesting. That may be it. So it's not jQuery's fault; the browser is rearranging the tags since DIV is not allowed inside P.

Comment: @DougS: Yeah; it's neither jQuery's fault nor the browser's, but yours. :)